# How to set interval for the particular function after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, set, intervals

I am having difficulties i performing code for setting interval for the $.get ajax method.. My code is found below...

```
setInterval(function () 
    { 
        passFunction(jsonData);
    } ,5);
$.get({
        url: 'pass.php',
        success: passFunction,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

    function passFunction(jsonData) {
        console.log("TSDebug jsonData.length [" + jsonData.length + "]\n");

        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
            var alert = jsonData[i]["alert"];
            var alertId = jsonData[i]["alert.id"];
            var groupId = jsonData[i]["group"];
            var hostnameAlias = jsonData[i]["alias.host"];
            var aliasIP = jsonData[i]["alias.ip"];
            var ipProto = jsonData[i]["ip.proto"];
            var tcpFlags = jsonData[i]["tcp.flags"];
            var attachment = jsonData[i]["attachment"];
            var service = jsonData[i]["service"];

            var timestamp = jsonData[i]["time"];
```

I have no idea on how to set the interval for this $.get ajax method. Can you please help me??Thank you

Comment: setInterval(passFunction(jsonData), 5000);

Comment: `Interval` works on milliseconds, set it to `5000` for 5 seconds.

Comment: Step 1: Learn the difference between a function reference, and a function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval` delay must be provided in milliseconds:

```
setInterval(loadData, 5000);

loadData() {
  $.get({
    url: 'pass.php',
    success: passFunction,
    dataType: 'json'
  }
}
```

Comment: by the way if i set to 3 mins... will it be 180000 or 30 *6000

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval()`method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals **(in milliseconds)**.

The `setInterval()` method will continue calling the function until `clearInterval()` is called, or the window is closed.

The ID value returned by `setInterval()` is used as the parameter for the `clearInterval()` method.

> Tip: 5000 ms = 5 second.

```
setInterval(function () 
{ 
  passFunction(jsonData);
} ,5000);
```